# Finding close numbers in columns of data

Tags: sorting

I have 3 columns of data (hours of the day)

> **C1 C2 C3**
>
> 01 05 00
>
> 05 09 06
>
> 11 11 10
>
> 16 17 14
>
> 20 22 18

I need to be able to separate this into an n by 3 matrix where the three numbers on each row are +/-2 hours away from each other. (The range of each row must be <=4)

Each value in each column can only be used once, so if there are more than one combination that uses the same number then one of the combinations is ignored.

So the final result would be:

> 05 05 06 (Taken from the 2nd in **C1**, 1st in **C2** and 2nd in **C3**)
>
> 11 09 10 (Taken from the 3rd in **C1**, 2nd in **C2** and 3rd in **C3**)
>
> 16 17 18 (Taken from the 4th in **C1**, 4th in **C2** and 5th in **C3**)

The data in each column must remain in that same column in the final matrix, for example the 16 found in **C1** needs to be in the first column of the final matrix.

I'm really struggling to find a way to put this into code, can you help?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this to almost work in MATLAB, I dont think its particularly efficient or clever but it does the job.

It relies quite heavily however on the value in the first column, treating it as a midpoint.

This means that the allowed points in columns 2 and 3 must be either `+/-2`.

The situation where the value in **C1** is a lower limit `(eg. 30)` and the other 2 values are up to 4 greater than the one found in **C1** is classed as invalid, although it is still technically a solution.

```
x = [1,5,0; 5,9,6; 11,11,10; 16,17,14; 20,22,18];

d=size(x); %Get the size in of x in the form [row,col]
rows=d(1); %Number Of Rows
cols=d(2); %Number Of Columns
clear d;

y = nan(rows,cols); %nan Matrix the same size as x used for the output

a = ones(1,cols); %Keep track of the current index in question in each column
c = 0; %Number of "matches" or rows that are valid in the output matrix

time = zeros(1,cols); %Keep track of the current values in each column

while(max(a)<rows+1) %For every row check that no index is invalid
    time(1)=x(a(1),1); %Get the value in column1
    b = 2; %column counter

    skip=0; %Increment the counter for column 1 if this is true

    while(b<cols+1&&~skip&&max(a)<rows+1) %For columns 2->cols, if we don't need to skip the value in column 1 and all the indexes are valid.
        time(b)=x(a(b),b); %Get the value in column b at row a(b)
        delta = time(b)-time(1); %work out the difference in value from the first column value that is selected
        if(delta>2)
            %Skip first column by 1
            a(1)=a(1)+1; %Increment the counter for column 1
            skip=1; %Return back to the first while loop
        elseif(delta<-2)
            %Skip b'th column by 1
            a(b)=a(b)+1; %Increment the counter for column b
        else
            %Its valid
            if(b==cols) %If at the last column and its valid
                c=c+1; %Increment the match counter
                y(c,:)=time(1:cols); %Set the c'th row of the output to what we've found
                a=a+1; %Move onto next number in column 1
                skip=1; %Start all over
            else %Not at last column yet
                b=b+1;
            end
        end
    end
end
```

**Final Result:**

> 05 05 06
>
> 11 09 10
>
> 16 17 14
>
> 20 22 18
>
> nan nan nan

Answer (score -1):

It seems although you are talking of having three columns of values, their row and column has no meaning. Effectively you have just a list of numbers: 01, 05, 00, 05, 09, 06, 11, 11, 10, 16, 17, 14, 20, 22, 18.

Then you order them: 00, 01, 05, 05, 06, 09, 10, 11, 11, 14, 16, 17, 18, 20, 22

Then you take three and look at their distances: 00, 01, 05 = bad, for 01 and 05 are too far apart. 
Next number. 01, 05, 05? No. Next number. 05, 05, 06? Yes. Continue after them. 09, 10, 11? Yes. Continue after them. 11, 14, 16? No. Next number. 14, 16, 17? Yes. You found a solution:

```
05, 05, 06
09, 10, 11
14, 16, 17
```

Comment: Which column they are in is important, The data in C1 must remain in the first column of the matrix, similarly the data in C2 and C3 needs to remain in the second and third columns of the final matrix. What row they are in however does not matter.

Comment: The column refers to a measurement in a set location, so C1,C2,C3 are recordings over time in different locations which is why I need to retain the knowledge of what column they were in. What I am trying to do is get all the data within a 2 hour time period from the 3 detectors into one row and say it is "approximately the same time" so I can compare between detectors. I hope this clears it up a little.

Comment: @Thorsten In the case where you have in let's say: C1=[0,1,2], C2=[4,5,6], C3=[9,10,11], your solution doesn't work. The column indices are important

Comment: Ah, now I see my mistake. Sorry. I'm going to think about this again.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Note: There should be no solution in the example given by Thierry

Comment: Yes, thanks, I got it ;-) I am aware of my mistake. Only, I don't see a good solution yet. One could just loop through all permutations of the numbers in the columns and look for good rows. This would be straight-forward, but not at all what one would call a clever algorithm. I'm somehow stuck there. I'll come back in case I get some better idea...